# loopback file system is slow

Tags: performance, loop-device

I created a virtual file system as follows:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/tmpfs/fs.img bs=4096 count=600000
mke2fs -F -t ext4 -q /home/tmpfs/fs.img
mount -o loop=/dev/loop6 /home/tmpfs/fs.img /home/test
```

Running `dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/tmpfs/testfile bs=4096 count=1000`
yields

```
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
4096000 bytes (4.1 MB) copied, 0.00143575 s, 2.9 GB/s
```

Running `dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/test/testfile bs=4096 count=1000`
yields

```
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
4096000 bytes (4.1 MB) copied, 0.00361518 s, 1.1 GB/s
```

I expected the performance to be the same so I wonder how this degradation can be explained? How could I improve the performance? I am running this setup inside a Docker container.

Answer (score 3):

Writing to `/home/test/testfile` goes through two filesystems, the the ext4 filesystem that you've written to `/home/tmpfs/fs.img` and whatever filesystem that's exposing `/home/tmpfs`.  Whether that alone would account for a 50+% performance impact, I don't know, but I would expect it to have a performance impact.

Comment: Good point but this causing 50% impact appears a bit odd to me... Can you think of a way to speed things up? I want to run a DB2 instance for integration tests using tmpfs. However, DB2 does not seem to work on tmpfs directly which is why I need the additional file system layer.

Comment: Sorry -- I don't have any experience with DB2 and don't have any ideas for how to speed it up in this case.